# Making AJAX call from chrome extension to Meteor web app

Tags: ajax, mongodb, meteor, google-chrome-extension

Hi I have made a web app to practice Meteor and am now trying to make a companion chrome extension. I am having difficulty finding resources on how to make AJAX calls to my meteor app/mongodb.

An example of what I am trying to do is find specific words on a webpage and search them in my mongodb.

Any resources or information on how to best do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you know how to make Ajax call from client. So you are having difficulty in building a REST API in Meteor. Although it is not recommended to build a REST API with Meteor, you can still do it. If you use case just require a REST API and does not have much to do with reactivity, I think you should not go with Meteor, just Node and Express should be fine.

But if you really want to use Meteor, here is the solution: Meteor has a package named [`webapp`](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html) which let you handle HTTP requests, that is enough for building a simple REST API. If you API is more complex, check out this community package [nimble:restivus](https://atmospherejs.com/nimble/restivus) it has a better API and useful functions